# update_user_meta() does not work

Tags: database, ajax, user-meta, session

I asked a question yesterday, but I realised that the code was not correct and it was my bad, so I refactored everything. I have a form with two fields which when user submits and takes a quiz test, gets registered and his scores saved to user meta data table. My user gets created, but when I want to add extra meta data of quiz scores for him using `update_user_meta` it just doesn't do anything. Here is my code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit_contact'])) {
   $email = $_POST['email_contact'];
   $full = $_POST['fullname_contact'];


    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["name"] = $full;
    echo $_SESSION["mail"];
   }

function save_quiz_score() {


     $score = $_POST['score'];


    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    $username = $_SESSION["name"];
    $user = get_user_by("email", $email);
    register_new_user($email, $_SESSION["email"]);
    update_user_meta($user, "quiz_scores", $score);

    echo $_SESSION["mail"];

 }
```

I'm using `session_start` and echo the sessions out and can see the emails, so that is no problem. `$_POST['score']` is also valid, because in the past I tried saving it on its own and it worked fine, so neither is that a problem. I just feel like I tried everything and feel like giving up. Maybe an extra pair of eyes can help me and notice a problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the variable `$user` before you created this user..

It should be like this and you need to check if the user already exists

```
$user = get_user_by("email", $email); // Its return you the user object
if($user) {
    update_user_meta($user->ID, "quiz_scores", $score);
} else {
    $user_id = register_new_user($email, $_SESSION["email"]);
    update_user_meta($user_id, "quiz_scores", $score);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by changing these lines:

```
register_new_user($email, $_SESSION["email"]);
update_user_meta($user, "quiz_scores", $score);
```

To this:

```
$registered = register_new_user($email, $_SESSION["email"]);
    update_user_meta($registered, "quiz_scores", $score);
```

In the first example, I was trying to get the user from database before actually registering it:

```
$user = get_user_by("email", $email);
```

So using `$user` variable inside `update_user_meta()` just didn't work.